# $.ajax post empty array

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to post browser's `geoposition` via jQuery Ajax

```
if (window.navigator.geolocation) {
    var failure, success;
    success = function(position) {
        var stringData = JSON.stringify(position, null);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'file_2.php',
            data: { data: stringData }
        });
    };
    failure = function(message) {
        alert('Cannot retrieve location!');
    };
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, failure, {
        maximumAge: Infinity,
        timeout: 5000
    });
}
```

But when its received in file_2 the array is empty and throw this alert "Notice: Undefined index: coords in..."

file_2.php

```
if(isset($_POST['data'])){               
    $dataString = $_POST['data'];      
    $Geoposition = json_decode($dataString, true);
    $lat = $Geoposition['coords']['latitude'];
    $lng = $Geoposition['coords']['longitude'];
}
```

Comment: try doing,  print_r($_POST) on the page file_2.php

Comment: also I think you should set your dataType: 'json'  

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Hi there..  print_r prints {}   ..and setting dataType didn't produce a change.. thanks

Comment: if you use chrome or firefox, you can see in the network log, if anything is being posted

Answer (score 0):

Based on the log, **stringData**'s value is **{}**. Its empty

Comment: Check stringData's value first before posting it to the server

Comment: `console.log` and the `network` developer tab are your friends for this sort of stuff.

Comment: I've already done that. console.log(stringData), it prints the same {} when it should show the geoposition array as a string. Seems like JSON.stringify not working?

Comment: seems like the case, it gets nothing.